# HighChart - How to change the icons of the highchart legend?

Tags: highcharts

I want to change the icons/bullets of the highchart legend, Is it possible to customize this?

Thanks for your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/9oz9h3pb/1/

```
//An example of a graphic from the HighCharts page:
//http://jsfiddle.net/9oz9h3pb/1/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide legend markers using CSS:

```
.highcharts-legend-item .highcharts-point,
.highcharts-legend-item .highcharts-graph {
  display: none
}
```

Then set `useHTML` in legend and insert your own HTML using `labelFormatter`:

```
  legend: {
    useHTML: true,
    labelFormatter: function() {
      return "<img src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/538262176134221824/Vx4_Psj1_400x400.png' width='20' height='20'> " + this.name
    }
  }
```

To make the legend look better move all items a little bit to the left:

```
this.legend.allItems.forEach(function(item) {
  item.legendItem.attr({
    x: item.legendItem.x - 10
  });
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/k6k9L31k/

**API references:**

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.useHTML 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormatter

Comment: Thanks bro, this is very useful. I used labelFormatter just to change the color of the text.

Comment: How to do this in Java ?

Answer (score 1):

you chan do it using [symbolRadius](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/legend.symbolRadius) to make it square

```
legend: {
        symbolRadius: 0
    },
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wafq2m17/)

Note If you more customization ie want image  then check this [Highcarts custom legend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45788558/3898339)
 and [Change size of legend symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46406947/3898339)

Comment: Thanks bro, but I wanted to put different symbols for each item.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you can read more about highchart API and researching more before create the question next time.

This is document

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.useHTML

===This is solution===

Simple way: change the maker type

http://jsfiddle.net/anchika/gb32bx2j/1/

Use the HTML

https://codepen.io/kevintcoughlin/pen/WrKLMe

http://jsfiddle.net/raskalbass/49pre/

```
Code jsfiddle
```

Comment: I wanted to put different symbols for each item in the legend, now I know how to do it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This, better?

```
labelFormatter() {
      const hTmp = '<div style="background-color: ' + this.color + 
      ';height:10px;width:10px;display:inline-block;border-radius:50%;"></div>';
      this.legendItem.x = 0;
      return hTmp + '<div style="display: inline-block;padding-left: 10px;">' + this.name + '</div>';
  },
```