# Highcharts: How to use a different icon in legend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, highcharts

So I made a chart that looks like this:

[Highcharts columnrange chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzQoJ.png)

(I used a hack to get those arrows on top of the bars. As you can see in the legend, it's really a wide horizontal image.)

Is there a way to insert a different icon in the legend, or maybe a custom SVG?

For now, I can at least hide the legend icon this way:

```
.highcharts-legend-item image {
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

I tried using the ::before CSS pseudo-selector, but nothing showed up:

```
.highcharts-legend-item image::before {
    content: "<svg height="64" width="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64"> <polygon fill="none" stroke="#FF8A65" stroke-width="4" points="30,4 4,60 60,60"/><polygon> </svg>"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the [Api Doc](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.marker.symbol) to add custom marker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HighChart - How to change the icons of the highchart legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551316/highchart-how-to-change-the-icons-of-the-highchart-legend)